# keep getting error /Users/newuser/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory when trying to connect to ssh agent. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Tags: shell, github, ssh, terminal

I'm following the github instructions on how to set up ssh key and add it to the ssh agent. However after I input `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` into the terminal, I receive this error: `/Users/newuser/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`

I set up my ssh key using `Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/newuser/.ssh/id_rsa)` so I believe its the correct name.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `newuser` us the username of the person logging in via `ssh` --  Is the username in fact `newuser`?

Comment: hey @Zak thanks for getting back to me! I found my issue. When I was following the github instructions, I specified a different file location rather than using the default `/Users/newuser/.ssh/id_rsa` file path.

I learnt a lot about hidden files today  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have been following the same instructions and meet the same problem. This is what worked for me:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-add id_rsa
```

Comment: Finally, two hours following every single step of each troubleshooting season at Github's page and your simple command solved my problem, I had to change id_rsa for the SSH SourceTree automatically generated and it worked fine. I owe you a pint :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/YOURNAME/.ssh/id_rsa): ***id_rsa***
2. Use the key in id_rsa.pub to add SSH Key
3. $ ssh -vT git@github.com
   Screen will display:
   You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.